# Using Ansible to change host folder permissions

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm using Vagrant to run a playbook-local.yml file to create a local dev environment that runs 95% of the same roles as the main playbook.yml which will eventually become what creates our stage/prod servers. When creating a local environment I have 4 directories and 2 files that I need to change the permissions for on the host machine (in this case my MacBook). Changing the directory permissions on the guest machine doesn't seem to work. When I SSH into the guest and try to chmod something, it just doesn't change, but it changes when I do it from the host.

My question is, how can I get Ansible to change folder and file permissions on my host computer so when the project is setup there is no need to manually do this? Here are some things I've tried:

```
- name: Set folder permissions to 0775
  shell: scripts/set-perms.sh // This runs the chmod commands
  connection: local
```

And this:

```
- name: Set folder permissions to 0775
  become: true
  connection: local
  command: sudo find "{{ item }}" -type d -exec chmod 0775 {} \;
  file: path={{ item }} mode=0775 state=directory recurse=yes
  with_items:
    - ../../../../www/system/cache
    - ../../../../www/_images
    - ../../../../www/app/templates
    - ../../../../www/html-assets
```

I've googled the crap out of this and none of the suggestions I've found work. The most common error I get is its asking for sudo password (below). If I need to provide a password while Ansible is running thats fine, but how do I do that?

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files/directories on your host machine are owned by the same user running the playbook you don't need `become: True` or `sudo` in your `command` module.

```
- name: Set folder permissions to 0775
  become: False
  connection: local
  file: path={{ item }} mode=0775 state=directory recurse=yes
  with_items:
    - ../../../../www/system/cache
    - ../../../../www/_images
    - ../../../../www/app/templates
    - ../../../../www/html-assets
```

Alternatively if the files/directories are owned by another user you will need to revert back to `become: True` and either supply a become password to your ansible-playbook command or set up passwordless sudo on your host machine.  Since you're using vagrant you'll probably want the latter.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer, thank you. It ended up working for me.